# Есть ли какой-то способ или ПО, чтобы использовать MacBook как второй монитор для Windows 11?

Tags: windows, macos, mac, экран, macbook

У меня есть Honor MagicBook на Windows 11 и MacBook Air 2017 13". Я хочу MacBook использовать как второй монитор, у винды есть встроенная функция "повторение экрана", но её видимо можно использовать только с другими устройствами на винде. Винду через буткемп установить не могу, т.к нет места для второго тома.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы сделать iMac как монитор потребуется кабель Thunderbolt.

1. Его надо подключить к обоим устройствам в соответствующие порты.
2. Обратите внимание, оба компьютера должны быть включены или выведены из режима сна.
3. Теперь на клавиатуре iMac, который будет использоваться как внешний монитор надо одновременно нажать комбинацию Command + F2. Кнопка Command находится слева от пробела.
4. В стандартный режим отображения iMac возвращается повторным нажатием Command + F2..

Comment: У меня не iMac, а MacBook, но я так понял смысл не меняется?

Comment: Да, смысл не меняется, я Вам помог?